# Django Rest Framework authentication and user session

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add authentication to my django-react app. At this point I am able to login/register users and it works fine but I want to get only data which is related with user logged in so posted or updated by them. Now I get all data regardless of user which is authenticated.
I assume I have to change it in my views but how to do this?
This is one of my classes

```
class ListView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ListSerializer
    
    queryset = List.objects.all()
```

And on frontend side I get data this way:

```
  const getList = async () => {
    try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get('/list/')
    if(response){
    setList(response.data)
    }
    }catch(error){
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django Rest Framework to set the authentication scheme on a per-view or per-viewset basis. Using the APIView class-based views:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ExampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': str(request.user),  # `django.contrib.auth.User` instance.
            'auth': str(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Remember to set it up:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Read more [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)